# Отправка данных с помощью JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Как с помощью `JavaScript` отправить данные из формы в PHP и при этом не перезагрузить  страницу

Comment: будут вопросы "Что такое гугл?"?

Answer (score 2):

[AJAX](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

> подход к построению интерактивных пользовательских интерфейсов веб-приложений, заключающийся в «фоновом» обмене данными браузера с веб-сервером. В результате, при обновлении данных веб-страница не перезагружается полностью, и веб-приложения становятся более быстрыми и удобными.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX, но если от него где-то "треснет", то его же функции через фреймворк JQuery (гораздо проще).   :)

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравится пользоваться этой штукой $.post('index.php', { переменная : значение }); или вот ещё

---

$.getJSON('system/UI.php?user=auth', {authLogin: authLogin, authPassword: authPassword}, function(obj){
 lessonList();
});

---

тоже чёткая функция)) а вообще, можно пошариться здесь например  http://originalip.ru, поглядеть примеры с реализациями. Они довольно разнообразны. Если сказать про собственный опыт, меня не подводили ещё)только кривые руки иногда